# Are a vector subspace and its orthogonal complement disjoint sets, or do they share a zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

My question really is that simple.  I am working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am inclined to believe the zero vector expressed on the basis of a proper subspace is distinct from that which is expressed on a basis of the orthogonal complement subspace.  But all zero vectors of subspaces correspond with the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So for example the $Z$ axis and the $X\times Y$ plane intersect at the origin of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I don't recall ever having this clarified.

Comment: The element $0$ in contained in every vector space. Subspaces of one vector space share the same $0$.

Comment: I certainly have no compelling counterargument.  Is this considered vaccuously true?  If it's true for vectors, then, I guess it's true for tensors of any rank and order.  And, since the real numbers form a vector space, all zero vectors and zero tensors are the real number zero.   Do you have a reference I could consult, and cite?

Comment: "all zero vectors and zero tensors are the real number zero." No, this is going too far! Every vector space has a zero vector, but different vector spaces may have different zero vectors. But since a subspace is a subset of an existing vector space, it inherits the same zero vector.

Comment: Rahul. Are there any vector spaces other than the null vector space which don't have a 1 dimensional subspace?  The number 1 is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^1$. The number 0 is the zero vector.

Comment: Of course not, the span of any non-zero element is a one-dimensional subspace.

Comment: "One must be able to say at all  times -instead of points, straight lines, and planes - tables, chairs, and beer mugs." ~~ Hilbert.  The inverse transformation is typically more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is literally just a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So, its zero vector is literally just the zero vector $(0,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  In particular, every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the same zero vector.

Comment: In general, it is not permissible to add vectors having differing numbers of components.  Similarly for contracting non conforming tensors.  For example, we cannot form the dot product of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  A non-zero vector which lies entirely in a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ will coincide with the zero vector in the orthogonal complement,  But is not the zero vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Another example $\left\{x,y,z\right\}=\left\{a,b\right\}$ is typically considered to be a meaningless expression.  So without some additional rule or convention $\left\{0,0,0\right\}=\left\{0,0\right\}$ would also be meaningless.

Comment: You are just spouting off words and don't understand what any of them mean.  Try actually reading the definitions in a linear algebra book (and take the definitions literally; they mean exactly what they say). As I said in the answer, if $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that means that $V$ is in particular a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so every element of $V$ is literally an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  There's nothing more to it.

Comment: In particular, expressing a vector in a basis doesn't change what the vector _is_.  If I pick a basis $e_1=(0,1,2)$ and $e_2=(1,0,1)$ for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then write the vector $(3,1,5)$ as $e_1+3e_2$, it's still literally the vector $(3,1,5)\in\mathbb{R}^3$; I've just written it a different way.  It does *not* magically become equal to $(1,3)$ just because I wrote it as a sum of two terms with $1$ and $3$ as the coefficients.

Comment: Ok, now I understand my confusion.  In terms of linear algebra and sets, this is obvious.  It is less obvious in terms of differential geometry where there are intrinsic and extrinsic representations.  Especially because many authors in mathematical physics claim the embedding space is an artifact of the intrinsic geometry.  So, I was thinking in terms of the isomorphism between an m-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.  In terms of differential geometry, that is a reparameterization.  I tried to change my down-vote, but it is "locked".  Beer and math don't mix, BTW.

Comment: As for my just spouting off words see pages 34 through 44 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3JIzmJugWS2_JPSfTsOVL6_K6uaq6Cy/view?usp=drivesdk and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEG08GmPvJbsqu4p-cRDONn-wEb8updw/view?usp=drivesdk and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9dw1vnWtnR-2KN4oIweHR6QnTJhs0fs/view?usp=drivesdk and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NYMWfLyosWY5SCXxpr4NayowYoFBTpgT/view?usp=drivesdk and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pggxdPRKfAbrrJlC0S9n-tmnOZ_r-vG4/view?usp=drivesdk and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KoYOK1fTwCoNPmt32QEG4iIcpzSWjDdt/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: And since we are discussing linear algebra, this is how I do it.  Much of the notebook is in transition from the index placement convention used by Wrede and my own.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORZqfAkAi7eqp3TP2NXLfhcY6B58brX8/view?usp=drivesdk